# Test an Async function in JS - Error: "Did you forget to use await"

Tags: typescript, async-await, jestjs, es6-promise

My code looks like this:

```
public getUrl(url) {
//returns URL
 ... }

public getResponseFromURL(): container {
  let myStatus = 4;
  const abc = http.get(url, (respon) => 
  const { statusCode } = respon;
  myStatus = statusCode;
  console.log('Inside callback' +myStatus);
  .on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Things have gone wrong' + err);
  });
  console.log('ITS COMPLICATED' +myStatus);
  return new Container(status, body, header);
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is because of the asynchronous nature of JS and the console.log('ITS COMPLICATED') gets executed before the one in the callback function. I am trying to have the first one executed before the last console.log!

I am using Async/Await like below:

```
  public timeoutPromise(time: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(Date.now());
      }, time);
    });
  }

  public doSomethingAsync() {
    return this.timeoutPromise(1000);
  }
```

As a result changed my getResponseFromURL() to:

```
public async getResponseFromURL(): Promise<container> {
    this.myStatus = 7;
    console.log(0);
    await this.doSomethingAsync();
    console.log(1);
    const abc = http.get(url, (respon) => {
      const { statusCode } = respon;
      this.myStatus = statusCode;
      console.log('Inside Callback ' + statusCode);
    }).on('error', (err) => {
      console.log('Things have gone wrong ' + err);
    });
    await this.doSomethingAsync();
    console.log(2);
    await this.doSomethingAsync();
    console.log('Is it simple lalala ' + this.myStatus);
    await this.doSomethingAsync();
   }
}
```

The problem with doing this was if my container class (return type of getResponseFromURL()) is a container for status and body when I am testing this async function, before `expect.getResponseFromURL().getStatus().toBe(200)` would work.

Test looks like below:

```
  test('Async function', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    const data = await ContainerGlobals.getResponseFromURL().getStatus();
    expect(data).toBe(207);
  });
```

Now I am getting error from `.getStatus()` and I am not sure how to bypass this error?

> "does not exist on Promise"

Comment: You could try something like this 

async doSomethingAsync() {
    this.asyncResult = await this.httpClient.get(this.url).toPromise();
    console.log('No issues, I will wait until promise is resolved..');
  }

Comment: @AnoopMc I am not sure I understand - what is this.httpClient and toPromise() here ?

Answer (score 5):

In the code above `await` is called on the result of calling `getStatus` on the result of calling `ContainerGlobals.getResponseFromURL()`.

`ContainerGlobals.getResponseFromURL()` returns a `Promise` and immediately calling `getStatus()` on the `Promise` gives an error since `getStatus` "does not exist on `Promise`".

`await` needs to be called on the `Promise` returned by `ContainerGlobals.getResponseFromURL()`, and `getStatus` should be called on the result returned by `await`.

The quickest way to fix this is to throw parenthesis around the `await`:

```
test('Async function', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const data = (await ContainerGlobals.getResponseFromURL()).getStatus();
  expect(data).toBe(207);  // SUCCESS
});
```

...but you might want to split the `await` line into two lines for readability:

```
test('Async function', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const result = await ContainerGlobals.getResponseFromURL();  // let the Promise resolve
  const data = result.getStatus();  // call getStatus on the result
  expect(data).toBe(207);  // SUCCESS
});
```